# Como iterar una lista en python

Tags: python, json, lista, response

Tengo este diccionario en python solo que no tiene la estructura clave:valor, solo contiene valor, por lo que quiero asignarles un nombre a cada elemento de esta lista, estoy haciendo este codigo donde quiero acceder a cada valor pero estoy atorada, si pudieran ayudarme se los agradeceria muchisimo :D

La lista es esta:

```
'facets': [{'name': ['juana', '40', 'gladiola', '67 564 78 65', ],
```

El resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

```
nombre: juana, edad: 40, calle: gladiola, telefono: 67 564 78 65
```

El código es este:

```
response = response.json()
data = []    
response = response['facets']
for r in response:
    for ee in r['name']:
        dd={'nombre':str(ee[0]),'edad':str(ee[1]),'calle':str(ee[2]),'telefono':str(ee[3])}
        data.append(dd)     
print(data)
```

P.D. la lista la obtengo de un json

Este es el error que obtengo:
`IndexError: string index out of range`

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es sencillo de resolver. Lo que está pasando es que mediante esta sentencia `for r in response` recorres la lista que está contenida en `facets` Que vendría a ser cada diccionario, para este caso solo hay uno y es este:

```py
{ 
    'name': [ 'juana', '40', 'gladiola', '67 564 78 65', ]
}
```

Al momento de hacer `r['name']` accedemos a la clave `nombre`, lo que devolvería la siguiente lista:

```py
[ 'juana', '40', 'gladiola', '67 564 78 65', ]
```

Y el problema viene justo ahí, justo en el segundo `for`.

```py
    for ee in r['name']:
```

Lo que haces ahí es recorrer la lista. La variable `ee` ahora reprensentará cada elemento de la lista

```
# ee tendrá estos valores:
'juana'
'40'
'gladiola'
'67 564 78 65'
```

Y la parte que da error es exactamente al momento de hacer `ee[0], ee[1], ... etc`
Como `ee` representa cada elemento, lo que haces con `ee[i]` es acceder a los índices de cada string que hay en tu lista y justo para el `'40'` no existe índice más allá del `1` y ahí el error `IndexError: string index out of range`.

La solución es sencilla. Si con hacer `r['name']` ya accedemos a la lista y lo que quieres es obtener los elementos de forma manual es de la forma en que ya lo hacías pero sin necesidad de otro `for`. Aquí un ejemplo:

```py
data = []    
response_ = response['facets']
for r in response_:
    ee = r['name']
    dd = {'nombre':str(ee[0]),'edad':str(ee[1]),'calle':str(ee[2]),'telefono':str(ee[3])}
    data.append(dd)     
print(data)
```

Otra forma de hacerlo si no quieres acceder manualmente a los elementos y quieres "automatizar" un poco más ese proceso y conoces el nombre de cada clave puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```py
data = []    
response_ = response['facets']
for r in response_:
    dd = {}
    for key, val in zip(('nombre', 'edad', 'calle', 'telefono'), r['name']):
        dd[key] = str(val)
    data.append(dd)     
print(data)
```

Lo que hace la función `zip` en palabras simples lo que hace es "emparejar" los elementos del primer iterable con los del segundo iterable, para este caso va a emparejar cada elemento de la tupla con cada elemento de la lista contenida en `r['name']`. Si la lista de llaves es muy larga sin problemas la puedes poner en una variable aparte.

Una forma más simplificada es la siguiente:

```py
data = []    
response_ = response['facets']
for r in response_:
    llaves =  ('nombre', 'edad', 'calle', 'telefono')
    dd = dict(zip(llaves, r['name']))
    data.append(dd)     
print(data)
```

El resultado en todos los casos es:

```
[{'nombre': 'juana', 'edad': '40', 'calle': 'gladiola', 'telefono': '67 564 78 65'}]
```